# Timestamps are showing server time, not local time

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp, localtime

I have a website where users(in different timezones) can create new records in a database, and i currently have each record being recorded with a timestamp of the time it was created...  I am in EST time zone, but when i view the records that i have created on the site, they show the time in MST, which also happens to be the servers time zone...  When i view the records in the database, the timestamp field is not converting to utc, it is instead converting to mst...  I have noticed that when i insert a record from phpmyadmin, i use the datepicker and select 18:35:01, but when i look at the record after its been inserted, it displays 15:35:01!!!  This is very frustrating, and i have been reading around that timestamp fields should automatically convert to utc, which mine is not doing...  Another thing is, i am currently using a date function to format the timestamp, which is displaying in 00-00-00 00:00:00 format, and that was giving me errors for a while so i started using strtotime, which may be part of the problem...  Im not sure...  When records are inserted into the database i am using null for the value so it will automatically use current local time...  But the thing is, different people from different timezones will be creating records than people who view them...  So i need to acommodate for all of that...  Any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I store all my stuff as epoch and use javascript to display it in the users local time.  As far as I know, php can't automatically figure out what timezone the user is in.

Comment: How would i store it as epoch?

Comment: Would i save that as an int?  Or would i still store it as timestamp?

Comment: I store it as an int, but it's only good to 2038 right now!

Comment: 2038 isnt a problem at the moment, and thanks so much!  Do you know where i could find out how to figure out the users timezone and convert it using javascript?

Comment: If your users have to log in, just ask them for it nd store it in your database. Otherwise just use JavaScript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how would I handle the conversion?  I am pulling the timestamp from a database but I am putting it into a recordset and dealing with it later...  How and when would I need to utilize javascript to handle the conversion?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone used by your PHP script

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

[View the PHP Manual for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Ive tried that, but it wont change the time...  I think its because im taking a string from the database which is already in the wrong timezone...

Comment: Don't store your timestamp as as string - there are date and time types for keeping track of time.  Anyhow, if the time is stored in the database, you can also store the time offset.

Comment: But then what use is the timestamp datatype?  Im storing it as a timestamp datatype but in php i use strtotime to format the date...  But its showing the server time for some reason

Comment: Should i just start using datetime?  And how would i deal with time zones in datetime

Comment: Try storing the unix timestamp in one timezone (that of the server). When you pull it out of the database, change the timezone as needed for the current user. I wouldn't recommend storing each user's time in their own timezone.

Comment: So theres no need for converting to utc?

Comment: I imagine so long as all your database entries are in the same time zone, you should be fine. Just convert when you output.